# Proof of Euler's Totient Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, totient-function

I have seen quite a few proofs of Euler's Totient Theorem that $a^{\phi(n)}≡1 \pmod n$ for all $a$ relatively prime to $n$. However, none have been done using induction. That is what I have been tasked with, and I do not know where to start.

This is the hint I have been given by the instructor: "Go by (strong) induction on $n$ this time. It breaks into cases of whether $n$ is composite or a power of a prime. I needed a second induction for a power of a prime."

Comment: You'll need to do it with strong induction. Basic induction is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: I have been reading a lot about what (strong) induction is. I have never used it before, and am still confused as to what it means in terms of the base case and the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: @Michelle Strong induction is very similar to weak induction. Weak induction means you use something like $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$ while strong inductions means you use something like $P(1), P(2), \cdots, P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

We sketch  one of the inductions. Suppose that $n$ is composite but not a prime power. Then $n=kl$ for some relatively prime integers $k$ and $l$ with $k\lt n$, $l\lt n$. By the (strong) induction hypothesis, we have $a^{\varphi(k)}\equiv 1\pmod k$ and $a^{\varphi(l)}\equiv 1\pmod l$.  It follows that $(a^{\varphi(k)})^{\varphi(l)}\equiv 1\pmod{k}$, with a similar result if we interchange the roles of $k$ and $l$.

Thus $a^{\varphi(k)\varphi(l)}\equiv 1\pmod{k}$ and $\pmod{l}$, and therefore $\pmod{kl}$. This finishes the induction, since $\varphi(k)\varphi(l)=\varphi(kl)$.

---

Comment: I have been reading a lot about what (strong) induction is. I have never used it before, and am still confused as to what it means in terms of the base case and the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Why does $n=ab$ and not $n=kl$ for some relatively prime integers $k$ and $l$ as you have defined?

Comment: @Michelle: Thank you, fixed. I started with $ab$, then realized that in your post you were using $a$ for something else. So I changed to $k,l$, not quite successfully.